# Extracting a word from string with multiple lines

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was able to get a SQL statement that extracts a word which is located after the keyword and before a space.

```
select 
    left(tt.CadRemarks, charindex(' ', tt.CadRemarks) - 1) 
from 
    myTable t 
cross apply 
    (values (substring(CadRemarks, charindex('dispatch level: ', CadRemarks) + 16, len(CadRemarks))) ) tt(CadRemarks)
where 
    t.CadRemarks like '%dispatch level: %'
```

It was fine until I came across a record that had multiple lines of words, like:

```
Dispatch Level: B123
Problem area
```

Or

```
Dispatch level: 123A45
Dispatch Unit: XYZ
```

The statement prints out

```
B123 Problem
123A45 Dispatch
```

I need the result to be:

```
B123
123A45
```

How can I get rid of the "problem" or "dispatch" or anything that comes after the dispatch level value?

Comment: Show  us some more sample data, and its result. (Still formatted text, not images.)

Comment: this isn't a valid d mysql query, are you sure that you are using mysql?

Comment: @nbk - sorry. did not notice it.

Comment: add sql server it fits better there and you find easier an answer

Comment: You want to extract numbers? Please provide sample data & expected results. The current is not clear.

Comment: @sami - Sorry. Not just the numbers. I've updated the sample data. The extracted value contains both numbers and characters.